# Use of some more

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A: I ate all of pizza you gave me .
>
> B: There are some more slices If you want to eat.

Does the person B mean the larger amount of pizza or 
continuation of pizza by “some more “? If the B says there are larger amount of pizza What should I say after than when I use it . But if he talks about continuation can I use “a bit more “instead of “some more”? Can you please explain ?

Comment: [if you are still hungry or still want more. We don't generally say if you want to eat. That would be used like this: If you want to eat  pizza, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I am not sure I understand the question.

> There are some more slices if you want to eat

means

> There are still at least two slices available for you to eat if you want to

There is no necessary implication that more is left than was already eaten; that may or may not be true. I have no idea what a "continuation" of a pizza even means.

A "bit more" means "more but not by a great amount." The use of "some" does not necessarily imply "but not by a great amount" although it is not denied.

If this answer is not helpful, I apologize, but it is hard to figure out what you are really asking.

Answer (score 0):

By "the larger amount of pizza" I think you mean if there's more than half of the pizza left.

Pizza is usually cut into slices before being served. Let's say this particular pizza is cut into eight slices. Person B gives person A two slices. Person A eats them both and says:

> I ate all of the pizza you gave me.

Person B then states that there are some more slices:

> There are **some more** slices if you want to eat.

This could be anywhere from two to six slices, so less than half or more than half. Because they said "slices" we know there's more than one slice left (unless person B make a mistake).

Instead of this, person B could say:

> There is **a bit more** pizza.

This implies that there is not much pizza left, at least one slice but probably less than half a pizza.

Note that "some more" could refer either to slices of pizza or just pizza. "a bit more" can only refer to pizza, not to slices because "slice" is a count noun, whereas "pizza" is a mass noun. You can say "a few more slices" if there are not many left.

> some more pizza
>
> some more slices
>
> a bit more pizza
>
> a few more slices

I have only considered the case where there is one pizza. If there is more than one pizza, it is almost exactly the same, but "a bit more" pizza might be a greater amount of pizza (more slices) than with only one pizza.

If I haven't fully understood your question, please clarify it and I will update this answer.